# update data in all tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I am working on MVC4 project where i have update data in all tables.Here is scenario

I have three columns ClientID,Name and JobName..

User will select these 3 option from source dropdown and will select destination values for these 3 options..

When he click update i want update these 3 columns value with destination values in all tables.

Now 1st solution is to write manually update command on by one for all tables..

But is there any other way to do this operation fast and quickly.. and in case a new table created i have to write manually that table in list of update commands..

So what is best way to do this operation ??

Comment: Can try bulk update.. http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/184770/Sql-Bulk-Insert-Update

Comment: i am using linq-to-sql...will this work ??

Comment: MY internet connection has some problem and I couldn't check.. Try this.. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53669/Bulk-INSERT-UPDATE-DELETE-in-LINQ-to-SQL

Comment: Your data model is flawed if you need to update these fields all over the place. The relational model was designed to avoid redundancies.